# Process run using nohup in sleep state

Tags: linux, process, kerberos, nfs, nohup

Problem:
I am running 3 java processes on a server with 32GB RAM. I frequently face closed ssh sessions owing to network issues. So, I ran the command using 
**nohup bash script.sh >log-file 2>&1 &**.

Now I am running the process using nohup and additionally I am putting them in background. Still, after 2-3 hours of processing, my java process stops writing to a log-file. I checked **/proc/pid/status**. It shows that the process is sleeping but actually this should not happen in my case. When I am using top, it does not show my process in the list of top processes.

My question is how can I know the reason behind the waiting process ??
When I check the freemem using top, it shows that out of 32GB space, 30 GB is being used and only 2 GB is free. This means that my process is alive and occupying space but not running.

BTW, my server mounts my home and data using a nfs server and we use kerberos for authentication. So, can this be a problem ?? I am using a krenew command for the expiring kerberos ticket.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should setup the 3 java procs to run as daemons, versus using no hangup.

Comment: How would running it as daemon be more beneficial than running it using nohup ??

Comment: As a daemon, it would always stay memory-resident and run in background, when you init the machine. nohup is not reliable, that's a utility that was designed back in the 1970's, when dialup 300bps modems were used :)

Comment: my process is also memory-resident right now. Plus it is also running in background. The only problem seems that its STATE is sleeping most of the time.

Comment: daemons run at a higher priority than nohups. If the executable in your script is not constantly doing something, the kernels scheduler will put that proc to sleep and not get polled oftenly. Have you monitored the behavior of your executable to see how active it really is?

Comment: Does your script or executable have a sleep command in it? I would try running the shell debugger to observe its behavior. You can also try using cron or at to run your nohup script at frequent intervals.

Comment: .. You could also run the script with [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) so that you can detach the session and reattach it.

Comment: My program is actually a simulator program which reads trace-file and processes it in a loop. It never sleeps. So, how come the scheduler is putting it into sleep state ?? I mean if a program is always running, it should be in running state most of the time

Comment: Could be several reasons, example: system configuration, flushing of buffers, etc.. You could consume a lot of time debugging your existing setup, or experiment with the other alternatives I have provided.